# Suggest me Java Embedded Database for java desktop application

Tags: java, database, swing, derby

Hi I am developing a java Desktop App. I am looking for java embedded database which performance will be good if there are more than 10,000 records in a table.
I am thinking to use "derby".I may use "HSQL" and "H2" also.
so please help me to get good selection of database and you can suggest some other database also.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For 0 installation needs, H2 would be my choice...IMHO - The question you need to ask yourself, which one is going to accomplish what you need...

Comment: Not Java, but you might want to consider Sqlite, so you can leverage the knowledge gained from using it in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if performance is your only concern. have a look at [JPAB](http://www.jpab.org/All/All/All.html). and [here](http://www.jpab.org/Test_Description.html) is the test description.